# ELSE Statement Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I am using a field from a data extension for a personalization string within an email.

I have an if, elseif, and else statement. The if and elseif statement are working fine. However the else statement is not working. If a record meets the criteria for the else statement, the elseif statement is being populated.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
%%[ 
                                          
var @lastPurchaseDate

SET @lastPurchaseDate = AttributeValue("lastPurchaseDate")

         IF EMPTY(@lastPurchaseDate) THEN SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Shop Now & Save"      
             
             ELSEIF @lastPurchaseDate < 'Monday, October 11, 2021 0:00 AM' 
               THEN SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Time to Refresh Your Banner Messaging! Create New Banners & Save"    
               ELSE 
               SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Your Banners Look Great! Create More & Save " 
             
             
             ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: You cannot use a string with a date written literally in a greater/smaller comparison. Is that how your date is formatted in the data extension?

Comment: @zuzannamj it's a date field formatted as "Tuesday, January 11, 2022 3:24 PM"

Comment: That is comparing that date you wrote out as a string, not a date, which is likely what is causing the ELSEIF to always be true.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're trying to compare a string to a date. Which doesn't make sense for a computer.

Try to use the StringToDate function to compare a date created from string. Read more about this function here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/StringToDate.html

Your code would become:

```
%%[ 
                                          
VAR @lastPurchaseDate

SET @lastPurchaseDate = AttributeValue("lastPurchaseDate")

IF EMPTY(@lastPurchaseDate) THEN 
    SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Shop Now & Save"      
ELSEIF @lastPurchaseDate < StringToDate('10/11/2021 00:00') THEN 
    SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Time to Refresh Your Banner Messaging! Create New Banners & Save"    
ELSE 
    SET @lastPurchaseDate = "Your Banners Look Great! Create More & Save " 
ENDIF

]%%
```